# Parse JSON with .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, json

I have an app written in C# with version 2.0 of the .NET Framework. Unfortunately, I do NOT have the option of updating to a newer version of .NET.

My app is calling a webservice that returns some JSON. The returned JSON looks something like the following:

```
{"Status":1, "ID":"12345"}
```

I need parse this string and get the respective Status and ID values. If I was using a later version of the .NET framework, I would use the `System.Json` namespace. However, I do not have that luxury. I have no idea how to parse this response.

Does anyone know how I can parse this with C# in .NET 2.0?

Comment: Can you use third party external libraries in your application?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, James Newton-King's [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) supports .NET 2.0, and is fairly simple to work with.

I have used it numerous times, where .NET's JavaScriptSerializer just didn't cut it.

Answer (score 3):

you can, and should, do that with this library 
http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I was able to backport Mono's implementation of System.Json to C# 2.0 with a few minor changes.

You'll need 6 files from [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-4.8.0-branch/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json) or you can simply download my C# 2.0 project from [here](http://vm1.duckdns.org/Public/System.Json/System.Json.zip).

Comment: That's just  a default using statement that you can remove, I have added a link to a C# 2.0 project containing all the necessary files

Comment: System.Linq is only used for ToArray() and can easily be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use JSON.NET and [here is the article describing this](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/08/02/net-2-0-support-added-to-json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) isn't adapted for .NET Compact Framework 2.0.

I'm using [Json for the Compact Framework](http://jsoncf.codeplex.com/).

```
public class YourClass {        
  public int Status = 0;
  public String ID = "";
}

using CodeBetter.Json;

YourClass object = Converter.Deserialize<YourClass >(jsonString);
```

Answer (score -1):

For .net 2.0 you can you use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and can parse like this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourobject>(jsonString);`