# Parse JSON in .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: json, json.net, .net-framework-version

Can anyone help me to parse the JSON output in .net framework 2.0? I dont have to use external dlls like Newtonsoft and it seems that Datacontractserailizer and Javascript serializers are supported from 3.5 only.

whether i need to write it manually then? if so can anyone suggest me any idea on how and where to start please?

Comment: You can start by showing us your expected JSON result, and the POCO's (classes) you would like to use for the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Parse JSON with .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15116262/3744182) as linked below, agree?

Comment: When you write, *I dont have to use external dlls like Newtonsoft* do you mean, *I **cannot** use external dlls like Newtonsoft*?

Answer (score 0):

in fact , you can do that. I found a similar question like your question in below link.If it is your awnser so it was better you tried to search a little more. 
[Parse JSON with .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116262/parse-json-with-net-2-0)